# WordPress requirement

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm newly use WordPress and want to install WordPress on web host.
But I'm confuse in version selection. My web server support PHP Version 5.4
Suggest me which version of WordPress can run on above php version.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), the minimum to run wordpress is PHP v 5.6 although you could run it on 5.5 but without support.
The website says that:

> Note: If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to security vulnerabilities

So, I'm quite sure that PHP 5.5 and below may not supported and/or deprecated but still works!

Comment: While the link is helpful you're quoting the recommendation rather than the minimum. 5.2.4 and up will work fine.

Comment: @NathanDawson ... the blockquote above quotes the minimum and describes some issues with it.

Comment: @NathanDawson You should know better. You should **NOT** be using any PHP version older than PHP 5.5 (*at very bare minimum*). All previous versions have long time reached EOL, and is in no way supported anymore. Upgrades and bug fixes on PHP 5.5 was stopped almost 6 months ago and will reach EOL in July this year. The best version to run now is at least PHP 5.6 to ensure you get bug fixes and security upgrades. Downvoting the answer is bad taste. The OP did not ask for the minimum to make WordPress work

Comment: @PieterGoosen Agreed - I was highlighting a factual error in the answer however I appreciate my response is worded in a way that suggests older versions of PHP are acceptable. The OP states the server is running 5.4. While it may not be the recommended version of PHP it doesn't mean the author can't run the very latest version of WordPress.